# Why does cef browser look different when site hosted on win 2008 r2

Tags: bootstrap-4, cefsharp

I have an Angular 7 app, using bootstrap 4, that is displayed through cef sharp and the cef browser v47. When testing locally on Windows 10 it is working fine. When deployed on Windows server 2008 r2 however it shrinks to around 1/15th of normal size. So then I have to add this line in angular so that it looks normal
    Html {font-size: 15em;}
However that means I will have to have two different scss files - one for running locally and one for running on win 2008 r2.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you copy all the relevant bin/pak files? I've seen small font issues when users have forgot to include the locales folder. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29 for a list of files required. You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample to test how the current supported version runs on your `2008R2` machine, version `47` is old and unsupported, if it turns out to be a bug you'll need to either hack around as you've done or upgrade.

Comment: The locales folder and as far as I know all the relevant bin/pak files were included. Worse errors occur if you miss any of the the bin/pak files. After I upgraded to the latest Cef the error was still occurring. I have left that site now so I can't provide any more details.